# 「めく」の使い方、どのような場合に「めく」を使うのが自然ですか。

Tags: grammar, suffixes, morphology

[goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/217188/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%81%E3%81%8F/)によると、「めく」という接尾語はいくつかの品詞（動詞を除く）に付き、五段の動詞を作ります。作られた動詞の意味は「〜という感じがする」に似ています。質問は、一般に「めく」という接尾語はどのような言葉に付きますか。

辞書の事例を見ると、「今更めく」や「仄｛ほの｝めく」などといった例が辞書に項目を持っているので、「めく」の使い方には制限があると感じます。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yahoo!辞書には「～で終わる単語」で検索できる機能があります。結果はこちらです。

http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%82%81%E3%81%8F&ei=UTF-8&b=1&dic_id=jj&stype=suffix

**現代の日本語で動詞として一般的に使うことがあるもの：**

- 謎めく
- 色めく　（※「色めき立つ」の複合語の方が一般的）
- 時めく　（※ほぼ常にひらがなで書き、[この意味で](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/157742/meaning/m0u/)使う）
- 春めく / 夏めく / 秋めく / 冬めく
- うごめく
- きらめく
- ざわめく
- そよめく
- つやめく
- どよめく
- はためく
- ひしめく
- ふためく　（※ほぼ常に「慌てふためく」で一語のようにして使う）
- ゆらめく
- よろめく

ちなみに「きらきら」「ざわざわ」「そよそよ」「つやつや」「はたはた」「ゆらゆら」「よろよろ」などは、それぞれ擬態語としても一般的に使われます。

**現代ではそのまま動詞としては滅多に使われないが、派生語の方が一般的なもの：**

- 仄【ほの】めく　（※ほぼ使役形の「仄めかす」の形で使う）
- 古めく　（※「古めいた」「古めかしい」と名詞を修飾する形で使う）
- 艶【なま】めく （※「なまめかしい」と形容詞の形で使う）

**滅多に使わないけど自分が見たことはあるもの：**

- 今めく
- ののめく

他の見出しは見た記憶すらありませんが、かなり古い言葉が多い印象があります。

基本的に、「古い接尾語で、昔はproductiveだったが、今は特定の単語にしか残っていない」と考えればいいのではないでしょうか。現代人なら「[～っぽい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2391/5010)」や、[名詞の動詞化](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24351/5010)などで処理しそうです。

なお、「オタクめいた話し方をする」「年寄りめいたことを言う」のように、名詞について「～のような」の意味で使うことも可能ですが、やや文学的な表現になります。

Comment: (何か気持ち悪いものが)うごめく、(足どりなどが)よろめく、(炎などが)ゆらめく、(シャンプーの宣伝とかで)つやめく、花めく、とかもどうですか？(アイデアとかが)ひらめく、は違いますかね？「なきわめく」は違うってわかるんだけど、「めくるめく」ってどうなんでしょうね・・・

Comment: @choco 追加しておきました。語源はあんまり自信がないです。というかあの逆引き検索、重要な単語が出て来てないかも…。

Comment: 「年よりめいた」って言いますね。確かに、辞書に載ってないですね。「脅迫めいた」とか使ってる人もいるけど、探すの大変そう。。。

Comment: http://togetter.com/li/660688