# double ては in a sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-は

> 「……そも、この学園にはその軋みがないものね。**術式めいてはいるだけでは何も起きる訳がない、か**」

In this school there are no such conflicts.

And I really have no idea bout the second part.

Can someone explain it to me?

Added fantranslation of the bold sentence:

> With nothing but empty ceremonies nothing ever happens, i guess.

My understanding from following Naruto's advice of removing the second は brings me to this translations.

> Just because there are ceremonies does not mean that nothing happen.

Comment: I feel that double は in the second sentence is unnatural. One of them should be a typo...

Comment: Could you give me a translation of that sentence? I can't really grasp what it's trying to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two は in the second sentence, which looks unnatural to me. The author should have wanted to write either:

> - 術式めいてはいるだけで、何も起きる訳がない、か
>     It only *resembles* magic; there's no way something can happen, huh?
> - 術式めいているだけでは、何も起きる訳がない、か
>     Just because it resembles magic doesn't mean something can happen, huh?

- `noun + めく` forms a literary verb which means "look like ～", "resemble ～". It  happened to be asked very recently in this site ([see this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29863/5010)).
- I'm not sure if *ceremony* is the right word for 術式. 術式 in such a context usually refers to *magical procedure*, *magic circle*, etc.
- ～わけがない is "There's no way ～", "It's impossible that ～".

  - 何も起きるわけがない = No way something can happen; Nothing can happen